# Activity and visible Fragment not logging properly

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Learning about Activities and Fragments right now. I created a super simple app that logs what Fragment is being shown and the amount of times I've seen it. This is where things get bizarre...

My understanding is that if a specific Fragment is visible, it's own logcat I have in that Fragment should appear. But that's not the case, it seems to record other Fragment's logcat or nothing at all.

When I load my app, automatically it shows that "tab1" and "tab2" gets logged right away. This confuses me as I don't know why "tab2" would be called since "tab1" is the only Fragment visible on the screen. Also, why doesn't "tab3" get logged then? When I scroll over once to the right (to "tab2"), "tab3" gets logged. When I scroll over to "tab3", nothing gets logged. When I move back to "tab2", "tab1" gets logged... going back and forth between Fragments, I never see "tab2" appear again in my logcat. Also, it seems like whatever Fragment I'm actually on, it's respective logcat gets called.

Any help explaining this would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my MainActivity:

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapater(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewContainer);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapater adapter = new SectionsPageAdapater(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab2(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab3(), "TAB1");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Here's my Fragment1:

```
int number = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1,container,false);

    number ++;
    Log.i("tab 1", "number: " + number);

    return view;
}
```

Here's my Fragment2:

```
int number = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab2,container,false);

    number ++;
    Log.i("tab 2", "number: " + number);

    return view;
}
```

Here's my Fragment3:

```
int number = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab3,container,false);

    number ++;
    Log.i("tab 3", "number: " + number);

    return view;
}
```

And here's my logcat:

```
I/tab 1: number: 1
I/tab 2: number: 1
I/tab 3: number: 1
I/tab 1: number: 2
I/tab 3: number: 2
I/tab 1: number: 3
I/tab 3: number: 3
I/tab 3: number: 4
I/tab 3: number: 5
I/tab 1: number: 4
I/tab 3: number: 6
I/tab 1: number: 5
I/tab 3: number: 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ViewPager` component creates by default the `Fragment` that is shown on screen and the adjacent ones.

It is an optimization and you can change that behaviour with the method `setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)`. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Answer (score 1):

try to override method  in your frgament

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
    }
    else if (!isVisibleToUser){
        Log.d("TAG","Fragment not Visible ");
    }
}
```